# Not able to extract css using Webpack2

Tags: webpack-2, extracttextwebpackplugin

I am trying to extract all the css into one file, I am using webpack2 and i have extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.0.0-rc.0, the following is my code

**webpack**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
    entry: './app/main.ts',
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ['ts-loader'] },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader', publicPath: "./dist" }) }
        ]

    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html',
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true
            },
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'style.css',
            disabled: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",  
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT", 
  "devDependencies": {    
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",    
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.0",    
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",    
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",    
    "webpack": "2.2.1"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

**main.ts**

```
require('../app/content/custom.css');
import 'core-js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

when i try to run the webpack, i get the following error

[image]
I was following this tutorial for building webpack [webpack tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7V0OackwxY)

Comment: maybe worth it to update "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",

Comment: i tried to update extract-text-webpack-plugin to 2.1.0 along with webpack@2.2.0 but it is not working

Comment: "webpack": "2.4.1" and "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0" should work together take a look here: https://github.com/jquintozamora/react-typescript-webpack2-cssModules-postCSS/blob/master/package.json. Anyways what is the error when trying.

Comment: Anyways, try to use some webpack validator https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-validator as it seems to be webpack config format error.

Answer (score 0):

First you can safely remove the `const webpack = require('webpack')` from your `webpack.config.js`, it's not needed :)

Could you try to without `publicPath: './dist'` && `use: ['css-loader']` instead of `use: 'css-loader'` in `ExtractTextPlugin.extract()` ?